# How to access AngularJS {{curly-brace-value}} in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

From the question itself, I am sure you understand that I am not an angular/jquery expert.

I have a div generated using angular which looks like this:

```
<div id='my-div' style={{ang.style}}'>
This is content inside the div
</div>
```

As you can see the style for the div comes from angular. Is there any way I can get this value in jQuery?

If I do `$('#my-div').attr("style")` it just prints `{{ang.style}}`

I know this is not the right way to do it, but currently due to many constraints, I need to be able to get this value in jQuery at least as a temporary fix.

I hope the Angular/JQuery Gurus here will be able to help me...

Comment: Pretty sure `{{ang.style}}` renders into a string, so I don't see why you're getting what you're getting. Are you running the jQuery script wrapped in `document.ready`? Btw, correct the HTML of the div. `id` and `style` values need their own quotes. Unless that's the bug...

Comment: @lesssugar: {{ang.style}} does not render into a string outside of Angular Scope. If you view the HTML source or print the style attribute using regular javascript or libraries like jQuery, it will show up just as {{ang.style}}, not its value. Thanks for pointing out the single quote, it is a typo only in the question, not in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.css()` instead of `.attr("style")` in jQuery to get the computed property.